# VBA Runtime error while assigning variable to new worksheet name

Tags: vba, excel

From Cell A7 (Stock name) neww sheet want to create and data from google will be pasted in that newly created worksheet. In My Code instead of `x` if use directly a value like `DLF`, it works.

But, when I assigned the variable I am getting a `Runtime error 1004` in `Sheets.Add.Name = x` and `Runtime error 9` in `Set DataSheet = Sheets(x)`.

```
Dim ParameterSheet As Worksheet
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim ticker As String
Dim exchange As String
Dim interval As Integer
Dim numPastTradingDays As Integer
Dim qurl As String
Dim x As String
Dim y As Integer
Dim WS As Worksheet
y = 7
x = Range("A" & y)

Set WS = Sheets.Add
Sheets.Add.Name = x

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set ParameterSheet = Sheets("Parameters")
Set DataSheet = Sheets(x)

DataSheet.Cells.Clear
ticker = ParameterSheet.Range("A7").Value
exchange = ParameterSheet.Range("B7").Value
interval = ParameterSheet.Range("C7").Value
numPastTradingDays = ParameterSheet.Range("D7").Value

qurl = "http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?" & _
       "q=" & ticker & _
       "&i=" & interval & _
       "&p=" & numPastTradingDays & "d" & _
       "&f=d,o,h,l,c,v"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [Worksheet.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) is a property of worksheets and sheets, it is not a parameter in the [Sheets.Add Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839847.aspx).

```
'method 1
with Sheets.Add
   .Name = x
end with

'method 2
sheets.Add After:=sheets(sheets.count)
sheets(sheets.count).name = x
```

Those are a couple of ways to add and name a worksheet. There are a few others.

Answer (score 0):

replace 
     Sheets.Add.Name = x 
with
     ws.name = x

(you must refer to the ws object name property)